# PHP add query with GET method

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I making site with products where I can sort my products by price. So, first I search product and display result:

```
    <form action="" method="GET">                       
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>                      
        <select name="category" id="category_search">
            <option value="default">Pretraži po kategorijama</option>                       
            <option value="torbe">Torbe</option>
            <option value="tv">Tv</option>
            <option value="udzbenici">Udžbenici</option>
            <option value="vrtna_garnitura">Vrtna garnitura</option>
            <option value="vrtna_oprema">Vrtna oprema</option>
            <option value="zemljiste">Zemljište</option>
            <option value="zvucnici/slusalice">Zvučnici/slušalice</option>
        </select>                           
        <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="pretraži"/>                    
    </form>

    if(isset($_GET['search'])){
        $search = sanitize($_GET['search']);
        $cat = sanitize($_GET['category']);                         

        if(!empty($search)){
           $search_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `product_name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `category` LIKE '%$cat%'".$sql_price.' '.$sql);                                     

            while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query)){
                echo '<div class="product"><a href="product.php?id='.$results_row['id'].'"><img style="border:1px solid black;" src="'.$results_row['img_path'].'/'.$results_row['img_name'].'" width="230px" height="230px"/></a><br><div class="br"></div><strong>'.$results_row['product_name'].'</strong><br>Cijena: '.$results_row['price'].'kn</div>';
            }
        }                                                       
    }
```

Then I made two options of sorting products first:

```
<?php echo '<a href="search_site.php?search='.$_GET['search'].'&category='.$_GET['category'].'&sort=asc">Niža prema višoj</a>';?>
<?php echo '<a href="search_site.php?search='.$_GET['search'].'&category='.$_GET['category'].'&sort=desc">Viša prema nižoj</a>';?>
$sql = '';
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    if ($_GET['sort'] == 'asc'){
        $sql = " ORDER BY price ASC";
    }elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'desc'){
        $sql = " ORDER BY price DESC";
    }
}
```

And second:

```
<form method="get" id="price_form">
            Od <input type="number" class="price_input" name="min_price" id="min_price" placeholder="kn"/> do
            <input type="number" class="price_input" name="max_price" id="max_price" placeholder="kn"/>
            <button name="price_submit" id="price_submit">Kreni</button>
   </form>

<script>
                                    document.getElementById('price_submit').addEventListener('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var search = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['search']); ?>;
   var category = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['category']); ?>;

   var min_price = document.getElementById('min_price');
   var max_price = document.getElementById('max_price');

   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "search_site.php?search="+search+"&category="+category+"&min_price="+min_price+"&max_price="+max_price
    });
 });
</script>

$sql_price = '';
   if(isset($_GET['price_submit'])){
     $min_price = sanitize($_GET['min_price']);
     $min_price = (int)$min_price;

     $max_price = sanitize($_GET['max_price']);
     $max_price = (int)$max_price;

     if($min_price == ''){
        $errors[] = 'Minimalna cijena mora biti ispunjena';
     }elseif($max_price == ''){
        $errors[] = 'Maksimalna cijena mora biti ispunjena';
     }elseif($min_price < 0){
        $errors[]= 'Minimalna cijena ne smije biti manja od 0kn';
     }elseif($max_price < 0){
        $errors[] = 'Maksimalna cijena ne smije biti manja od 0kn';
     }elseif($min_price > $max_price){
        $errors[] = 'Minimalna cijena ne smije biti veća od maksimalne';
     }

    if(empty($errors)){
        $sql_price = 'BETWEEN '.$min_price.' AND '.$max_price;
    }else{
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
}
```

Second one don't work, I tried to make sort, when I press buttont to sort product by price from min price what user inputted to max price what user inputted, so I should get something like this:
[image]

but I get:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `search="+search"&category` there should be `+` before `&category`

Comment: @u_mulder still nothing...

Comment: `var search = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['search']); ?>;`

Comment: that shouldn't be a js string?

Comment: `var search = '<?php echo json_encode($_GET['search']); ?>';` << try this

Comment: Please use the MVC architecture, please. I beg you to.

Comment: Minimal, complete, verifiable example:  definitely.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

**I have updated old code. please try this code**
You no need to a tag because you can give an action in form tag to redirect the other page.

```html
   <form action="search_site.php" method="get" id="testing_form">                     
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>                      
<select name="category" id="category_search">
 <option value="default">Pretraži po kategorijama</option>                       
 <option value="torbe">Torbe</option>
 <option value="tv">Tv</option>
 <option value="udzbenici">Udžbenici</option>
 <option value="vrtna_garnitura">Vrtna garnitura</option>
 <option value="vrtna_oprema">Vrtna oprema</option>
 <option value="zemljiste">Zemljište</option>
 <option value="zvucnici/slusalice">Zvučnici/slušalice</option>
</select>                                            
Od <input type="number" class="price_input" name="min_price" id="min_price" placeholder="kn"/> do
<input type="number" class="price_input" name="max_price" id="max_price" placeholder="kn"/>
<button name="price_submit" id="price_submit">Kreni</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$sql_price = '';
if(isset($_GET['price_submit'])){

    $min_price = sanitize($_GET['min_price']);
    $min_price = (int)$min_price;
    $max_price = sanitize($_GET['max_price']);
    $max_price = (int)$max_price;

    if($min_price == ''){

        $errors[] = 'Minimalna cijena mora biti ispunjena';
    }elseif($max_price == ''){

        $errors[] = 'Maksimalna cijena mora biti ispunjena';
    }elseif($min_price < 0){

        $errors[]= 'Minimalna cijena ne smije biti manja od 0kn';
    }elseif($max_price < 0){

        $errors[] = 'Maksimalna cijena ne smije biti manja od 0kn';
    }elseif($min_price > $max_price){

        $errors[] = 'Minimalna cijena ne smije biti veća od maksimalne';
    }
    if(empty($errors)){

        $sql_price = 'BETWEEN '.$min_price.' AND '.$max_price;
    }else{

        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    $category = $_GET['category'];
}
$sql = '';
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){

    if ($_GET['sort'] == 'asc'){

        $sql = " ORDER BY price ASC";
    }elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'desc'){

        $sql = " ORDER BY price DESC";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain your question once again?? defiantly i will help you.

Comment: you don't have $_GET['sort'] input type which name is sort that's why your url string is blank.

Comment: now i found this url which you need.  http://localhost/search_site.php?search=jfrjfrj&category=default&min_price=67567&max_price=567657&price_submit=

Comment: My `$_GET['sort']` is in anchor `&sort=desc` and `&sort=asc`.
And I had two forms, one is for searching databasse and another is for sorting certain price as you can see, so I don't understand how is your solution all in one form?

Comment: I think that, problem is in my AJAX code because it does nothing when I press my submit button `price_submit`

Comment: ok...but you know, wecan't submit two form at same time then how you will pass the value of  get $_GET['search'], $_GET['category'], $_GET['max_price'] & $_GET['min_price'] because in your code you have two form. you can send in one form and give the action in form tag then you will find the that url which you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90217/discussion-between-manisha-chaudhary-and-crovg).